# Checking user input string

Tags: go

I am new in GoLang and I am encountering a problem with this condition:
Even if the input of the user is "1", it doesn't enter in the if statement.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "math"
    "strings"
)

func prompt(toprint string) string{
    if(toprint == ""){
        toprint = "Enter text :";
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin);
    fmt.Println(toprint);
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n');
    return text;
}

func main() {
    choice := prompt("Please enter '1'");

    if(strings.Compare("1",choice)==0||choice=="1"){
        // D'ONT ENTER HERE EVEN WHEN choice=="1"
    }else{
        // Always go here
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `reader.ReadString` returns all the text including the delimiter, so the string returned will be `1\n` not just `1`. From [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) (my emphasis):

> ```
> func (*Reader) ReadString
>
> func (b *Reader) ReadString(delim byte) (string, error)
> ```
>
> `ReadString` reads until the first occurrence of `delim` in the input, returning a string containing the data **up to and including the delimiter**. If `ReadString` encounters an error before finding a delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error itself (often `io.EOF`). ReadString returns `err != nil` if and only if the returned data does not end in `delim`. For simple uses, a `Scanner` may be more convenient.

Perhaps you want to do

```
return strings.TrimSpace(text)
```

at the end of `prompt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !
Here's the "prompt()" code which returns the correct input :

```
func prompt(toprint string) string{
    if(toprint == ""){
        toprint = "Enter text :";
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin);
    fmt.Println(toprint);
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n');
    return text[0:len(text)-2];
}
```